# Show that if $a\neq b$ then $a^3+a\neq b^3+b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cubics

Show that if $a\neq b$ then $a^3+a\neq b^3+b$

We assume that $a^3+a=b^3+b$ to show that $a=b$

$$\begin{align}
a^3+a=b^3+b &\iff a^3-b^3=b-a\\
&\iff(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=b-a\\
&\iff a^2+ab+b^2=-1
\end{align}$$
Im stuck here !

Comment: Note the last step is only true if $a\neq b$ - you can't divide both sides by $a-b=0$.

Comment: For the point you're at, you can use the quadratic formula.

Comment: The formula is $a^3-b^3=(a-b)\left(a^2+ab+b^2\right)$.

Comment: A calculus proof would note that $f(x)=x^3+x$ then $f'(x)=3x^2+1$ so $f$ is strictly increasing everywhere.

Comment: Note that $a^2+ab+b^2$ is between $a^2+2ab+b^2$ and $a^2-2ab+b^2$. (As noted by @user236182, the sign of the factorization is wrong.)

Comment: Just to be funny, let $a=i$ and $b=-i$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$a^3+a=b^3+b\iff a^3-b^3=b-a$$

$$\iff (a-b)\left(a^2+ab+b^2\right)=b-a$$

If $a=b$, then we're done. For contradiction, assume $a\neq b$. Then $a-b\neq 0$ and we can divide both sides by $a-b$:

$$a^2+ab+b^2=-1\iff 4a^2+4ab+4b^2=-4$$

$$\iff (2a+b)^2+3b^2=-4,$$

contradiction, because $(2a+b)^2+3b^2\ge 0$ for all $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

Using analysis: define $f(x)=x^3+x$. Since $f'(x)=3x^2+1>0$, the function is strictly increasing, hence, [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function#Definition), and the result follows.

Comment: One also needs continuity :0.

Answer (score 0):

If you have calculus, you can conclude this is impossible as follows, since $lim_{x, y \to \infty}x^2+xy+y^2=\infty$, there is a point where the minima is achieved. This point has vanishing partial derivatives, thus $\partial_x(x^2+xy+y^2)=2x+y=0$ and likewise $2y+x=0$, so $x=-2y=4x$ so $x=0$ and likewise $y=0$, so $x=y=0$, and we have a contridiction since $0^2+0*0+0^2=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a math major so I'm not sure about the formalism but does this work?

If a!=b,
Then a=b+d ; where d is a non zero integer.

Plug in to the expression (a^3+a)-(b^3+b) :-
3bd^2+3db^2+d^3.
This has only one real root which is d=0, which is a contradiction, so the two expressions cannot be equal.

Too informal? Correct or incorrect, math majors?